# Page width in iBooks

Tags: books, epub

Is there anyway to make the maximum page width in iBooks larger than 560 px?

I am using iBooks in Yosemite as an EPUB reader but find it frustrating that text columns' maximum width seems to be fixed at 560 px (see image).

EPUBs are basically HTML files and after some examination I realized that maximum width setting is something defined in iBooks, not the EPUB files themselves. Other EPUB readers work just fine (with no max width setting), but if possible I would like to use iBooks with a slightly larger page width.

Is there any sort of hack to get this done?

[image]

Comment: Not an answer, but I long ago gave up trying to use iBooks because of various limiting factors like this one. I used Stanza until it vanished from the store, now [Marvin](https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/appstafarian/id577374974) by Appstafarian, which is very good, but the full version is not free

Comment: Thanks.
After trying a couple of [apps](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/utilities-roundups/the-best-apps-to-read-ebooks-on-your-mac/), I have settled down with [Clearview](http://www.canoejoy.com/). With proper tweaking (default font, line spacing) it looks as good as iBooks, with better search functionality, plus the huge advantage of not having to copy and store all your epubs to a "Library". I think it is absolutely worth the $9 it costs.

Comment: Dang no answer! Why Apple, why do you lock us like this!? There's the option for one page or two, but if you make the window wide, it automatically goes to two! I have ebooks with tables in them, and I just want a way to let that table content breathe a bit :(